# jQuery: Input value lost on keyup?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form which I would like to submit (i.e fire ajax) when the user presses enter (return) on an input field. If I press the submit button the event fires fine, but when using keyup to fire the exact same function the value of the input field is blank. I tried passing the value of the input field (from the keyup function) using **$(this).val()**, but the passed param was still blank.

**Update II:** The problem only occours on initial load. After hitting refresh the events fire as intended. Tested in Chrome and FF.

http://jsfiddle.net/R5QsC/1/

```
// Value of #pin is blank in getKeyAjax()
$('#pin').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log('DEBUG: Keypress detected (13)')
        getKeyAjax();
    }
});
// Value of #pin is correct in getKeyAjax()
$('#btnPwdCreate').click(function() {
    getKeyAjax();
});

function getKeyAjax() {
    console.log('DEBUG: Starting ... getKeyAjax()');
    var txtPin = $('#pin').val();
    console.log('DEBUG: Value of txtPin: ' + txtPin);
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine here, right? (http://jsfiddle.net/swz5c/)

Comment: I've forgot to mention that it does indeed work, but only sometimes (most often, not). Which in turn makes it all that much harder to work out what's wrong. I've only tested in Chrome and FF so far though.

Comment: Hmm, can you set up a fiddle on jsfiddle.net with your HTML and JS?

Comment: @KGChristensen I am quite sure you aren't wrapping your jQuery code in a `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: It's in doc.ready - see comment to answer below.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R5QsC/1/ here. I'm baffled, works fine in the fiddle as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed on your fiddle one thing that might be causing this. In using the form field I noticed that sometimes I got an alert stating '4 digits only' and usually I did not. The problem there is your `form` tag. Hitting enter is triggering the browser's default behavior: a non ajax form submit. If this goes through before your `$.GET` has run, it would be consistent with the behavior you described, after refresh the js is cached and then might evaluate faster allowing the $.get just before the submit and refresh occurs. Its just a theory, but ultimately it leaves you with two options:

1. remove the `<form>` tag from your html.
2. `$('form').on('submit', function(e){e.preventDefault();});`

1# will have the effect of no default submits because there is no `<form>` to do so. 2# overrides the `onsubmit` event to prevent the default submit (letting you keep the form tag).

Whether this solves the problem you are after or not, you do need it for your script regardless. Its going to be key to performing ajax while hitting enter on an input inside a form.

http://jsfiddle.net/9TYhT/

Fiddle above. Behavior is now consistent.

Comment: Excellent - great reply and explanation. I went with suggestion #2, works on all targeted browsers now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // make sure DOM is ready to be manipulated
  // ...

    $('#pin').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            getKeyAjax();
            e.preventDefault() // prevents form from being submitted
        }
    });

  // ...
})
```

Comment: @KGChristensen do you use `$(document).ready()`, after DOM is ready to be manipulated?

Comment: I've tried both (just for the hell of it), at the moment it resides in doc.ready. Small update though: It seems to be working in Chrome now (after adding Raminson's suggestion and force cleaning Tomcat ...). No luck in Firefox though.